# sql Timestamp across app layers

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp

It is safe or convenient to use java.sql.Timestamp across all application layers?

We are using Postgres and need something like a Timestamp ... we ended up using this type on Persistence entities and, at the end, all the way up until services layer.

I see weird but not sure about what are the risk and problems that may arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking i realized that i don't want to my business layer be coupled with my persistence representation. This is why i don't like using SQL packaged classes ... i would want to keep those at the bottom level possible.

Otherwise if i decided to not use SQL anymore i still will have SQL packaged classes, or i should have to refactor business layer.

This is why i do not like

Answer (score 0):

`java.sql.Timestamp` inheritance `java.util.Date` then you can use this objects across all aplication layers. I use `java.sql.Timestamp` readed by `Spring JDBC` from db tables in my applications without any problems.